# Pod (PaymentKit) can't load images using imageNamed

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, stripe-payments

I'm updating my project to Swift 1.2

What has been done so far (changes from working project):

- Updated Xcode to 6.3
- Updated Alamofire to 1.2.0

  - Added it to Podfile
  - Added `use_frameworks!` to Podfile
  - Changed platform in Podfile 7.0 to 8.0
- Updated Stripe 3.0.0 -> 3.1.0

I also fixed some issues in my code (mostly changed `as` to `as!` for castings).

After that PaymentKit (it wasn't updated) stopped loading its image assets (backgrounds, card images etc).

I've checked in derived data - PaymentKit.framework contains all assets inside it. But code like `[UIImage imageNamed:@"mastercard"]` returns nil. I spent couple hours trying to solve it - no luck...

Any Ideas what can be reason for that?

**UPDATE**

I found the reason - `use_frameworks!` flag
But I don't know how to leave this flag (it's required by Cocoapods as Alamofire is a Swift Pod) and have working PaymentKit.
The only reason I can see right now - is adding Alamofire using `git submodule` or just incorporate it's course to my project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem here is that this pod is "not ready" to be a framework. They use imageNamed instead of

```
NSBundle(forClass: self.class()).pathForResource("amex", ofType: "png")
```

you can still get this images from your code this way

```
let image = NSBundle(forClass: PTKView.self).pathForResource("amex", ofType: "png")
```

The "dirty" workaround now is just import all resources from this pod to you image assets or just copy it in the main bundle.

Comment: I opened an issue on [PaymentKit](https://github.com/stripe/PaymentKit/issues/86)